# What is the best method for global var in function/class? PHP

Tags: php

my problem "is too many connection to MySQL" because i had created a new object for each function
that had needed it.

What is the best solution for this operation? There is other methods?

```
$db = connection(); // PDO

//1
function test(){
    $GLOBALS['db']->prepare(..);
}

// 2
function test2(){
    global $db
    $db->prepare(..);
}
```

Comment: A normal function argument?(But the nicer way is @RobP with a class!)

Comment: The best solution may not be a global at all, but rather a singleton class that keeps the connection around.

Comment: @RobP that's only slightly better. But it's a viable solution in some cases.

Comment: @Rangad I disagree it's only slightly better. What's your reasoning?

Comment: @RobP To have the connection nice and clean in one class which you can easy extend and look at is for me the nicest and cleanest way! You can tell in one sentence where all the code about the connection is.

Comment: @Rizier123 yes I agree.

Comment: any example? i don't have understood very good singleton

Comment: Compared to the global approach it's a massive step up (should edit my comment, came out a bit wrong). However, as a starting point: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/40610 (ignore the java talk, everything except multi threading applies to php) http://stackoverflow.com/a/138012/2912456 . However, as I should've edited in, in most cases if you have no special requirements it's still a viable solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say both are bad, pass the $db object in as an argument to the functions:

```
function test($db) {
    $db->prepare(...);
}
```