# How do I get rid of global $var; ? - PHP

Tags: php, oop, global

some people keep telling me that globals in a function aren't a really good idea.
I am not THAT good in PHP5 or OOP but i'm still learning. Now, my question to you is:

Is there a better way than doing this? :

```
<?php 
class Name {
     final public function Example() {
          global $db;
          $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
          ....
     }
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: This question was asked a few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27384782/3933332

Comment: Place your variable in the function.

Comment: @Rizier123 I'd say that can be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: `final public function Example($db)`

Comment: You can always use a static method in a class as a factory: `DB::get()->query("SELECT * FROM users")`.